# Is it good or bad to store log messages in a database table, rather than a file?

Tags: database, logging, web, language-agnostic

I'm talking about human-readable text logging, like error messages from a web application.

Do people commonly store these in a database? Are there any advantages to using a database table instead of a file? Or if not, why is it specifically a bad idea?

Answer (score 4):

## Database

Advantages:

- Way easier to search through the logs

  - Clever queries, grouping and limiting by for example dates
  - Retrieving log messages of a specific kind, log level or containing certain patterns
  - Filtering away unwanted noise when looking for specific things
- Easier to manage in a good way if you're creating some kind of user interface

Some disadvantages:

- Pollutes your database with stuff that might not be very useful, depending on your application
- Can aid in far quicker database growth, which might be annoying in certain scenarios
- You need access to the database (which might require paper work or simply takes time), or write a UI on top

## Text files

Major advantages

- Very easy, light weight, simple to implement
- Easy to clean away when not needed anymore; no longer wasting disk space
- Easy to scan (and thus give you a nice UI) with tools like Splunk or Logstash

Disadvantages

- Hard to browse and query (depends on your logging statements, file structures etc)

There's nothing inherently right or wrong with logging to a database versus logging to a file; it all depends on your needs. Think through your needs, then decide. Logging to a database is very convenient when debugging, but it might require more of you, your team or your application in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link gives you a better idea - 
[What's more efficient - storing logs in sql database or files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257242/whats-more-efficient-storing-logs-in-sql-database-or-files)

**Log to db instead if you need other people needs to read logs in a web interface or if you need the ability to search through logs**